# i want to crop the white area in a binary image

Tags: matlab

I have a binary image. i want to scan the image and find the numeric region of it.i think it should be a scanning and cropping process. how can I find the white rectangle and crop it?

[image]

Comment: Where exactly is the numeric region in this image?

Comment: it is in the white rectangle in the center of image. they are Farsi numbers. i tried a number of methods to crop this rectangle, but i didn't get the right answer.

Comment: Are you using the Computer Vision system toolbox in Matlab? If so, here's one description of a method to do something similar: [https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html]